# Emailing html with images

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik, export, richtextbox

I'm using Telerik controls. I'm having trouble emailing my `RichTextBox` content with inline images after its exported to html. I can export the `RichTextBox` contents to html completely fine but when the html is emailed, the image is a blank box with a border around it.

```
 <Telerik:HtmlDataProvider x:Name="HtmlProvider" 
                           RichTextBox="{Binding ElementName=EmailRichTextBox}"
                           Html="{Binding SelectedOnUser.EmailSignature, Mode=TwoWay}"  >
                           <Telerik:HtmlDataProvider.FormatProvider>
                               <Telerik:HtmlFormatProvider>
                                   <Telerik:HtmlFormatProvider.ImportSettings>
                                       <Telerik:HtmlImportSettings  UseDefaultStylesheetForFontProperties="True" />
                                   </Telerik:HtmlFormatProvider.ImportSettings>
                                   <Telerik:HtmlFormatProvider.ExportSettings>
                                       <Telerik:HtmlExportSettings ImageExportMode="Base64EncodedSplit"/>
                                   </Telerik:HtmlFormatProvider.ExportSettings>
                               </Telerik:HtmlFormatProvider>
                           </Telerik:HtmlDataProvider.FormatProvider>
</Telerik:HtmlDataProvider>
<Telerik:RadRichTextBox x:Name="EmailRichTextBox" Height="100"/>
```